# Replace values in xml remote file and save

Tags: php, xml, replace, find, preg-replace

I have a remote xml file: http://my-site/my-file.xml
This file has this values:

```
<files>

  <file>
     <unique>444444</unique>
  </file>
  <file>
     <unique>666666</unique>
  </file>
  <file>
     <unique>888888</unique>
  </file>

</files>
```

I need to use php to replace the value of `<unique>xxxxxx</unique>` to be half its value, so that the file should be change to

```
<files>

  <file>
     <unique>222222</unique>
  </file>
  <file>
     <unique>333333</unique>
  </file>
  <file>
     <unique>444444</unique>
  </file>

</files>
```

I got part of the function to open and save the file but not the find&replace code:

```
$xml_external_path = 'http://my-site/my-file.xml'; // THIS LINE MUST EXIST
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_external_path);// THIS LINE MUST EXIST

$searches = array();
$replacements = array();
foreach (....) {
    $searches[] = ....
    $replacements[] = ....
}
$newXml = simplexml_load_string( str_replace( $searches, $replacements, $xml->asXml() ) );

$newXml->asXml('new-xml.xml');// THIS LINE MUST EXIST
```

Comment: this is incorrect close tags - `<file/> <files/>` simplexml will not work with it

Comment: @splash58 was a typo, I just edited my post.

Comment: only for unique element?

Comment: @miglio yes, only that

Comment: The filename is invalid and the example stops the moment it reaches the line to operate on the return value of the load operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use preg_replace_callback for a pattern:

```
$txt = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<files>
  <file>
     <unique>444444</unique>
  </file>
  <file>
     <unique>666666</unique>
  </file>
  <file>
     <unique>888888</unique>
  </file>
</files>
XML;
// load the xml like a text
$xml_external_path = 'http://my-site/my-file.xml;'; 
$txt = file_get_contents($xml_external_path);

$pattern = '/<unique>(.*?)<\/unique>/';
$response = preg_replace_callback($pattern,function($match){
    $value = intval(trim($match[1]))/2;
    return '<unique>'.$value.'</unique>';
},$xml);

$newXml = simplexml_load_string( $response );//
$newXml->asXml('new-xml.xml');//create the xml

//print_r($newXml);
```

Comment: sorry but it is not working. Can you insert your code inside the xml functions of my code? I guess I get lost there.

Comment: not working, can you insert this code to start your code with these 2 lines: '$xml_external_path = 'http://my-site/my-file.xml;' and '$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_external_path);'

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$str = '<files>    
  <file>
     <unique>444444</unique>
  </file>
  <file>
     <unique>666666</unique>
  </file>
  <file>
     <unique>888888</unique>
  </file>
</files>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$set = $xml->xpath('//unique');
foreach ($set as &$item)
  $item[0] = $item/2;

echo $xml->asXml();
```

result

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<files>
  <file>
     <unique>222222</unique>
  </file>
  <file>
     <unique>333333</unique>
  </file>
  <file>
     <unique>444444</unique>
  </file>
</files>
```

Comment: Seems good but how do I get the new file file saved as 'new-xml.xml'

Comment: asxml with filename as argument

Comment: $xml->asXml('new-xml.xml');

Comment: Can you please start your code with this 2 lines: '$xml_external_path = 'http://my-site/my-file.xml';' and '$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_external_path);'

Comment: Change  only my 1st line to your two. All will work

Comment: I can't get working, can you please paste the complete code?

Comment: https://eval.in/393612

Comment: @JPashs: This is no code-ordering service here.

Comment: I get this error: 'Error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in line 29'. Line 29 is this: '$set = $xml->xpath('//unique');'

Comment: this is my code: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VWAjf7LD

Comment: it means your  xml not loaded by simplexml. Why? i don't know. say as first line `error_reporting(-1); ` maybe you see any error log

Comment: Is it still not working?

Answer (score 0):

A way with xslt:

```
define('XML_PATH', 'http://my-site/my-file.xml'); 
define('XSL_PATH', 'divide.xsl');

$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load(XML_PATH);

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load(XSL_PATH);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

where `divide.xsl` is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="unique">
    <xsl:value-of select=". div 2"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```